# Angular 11: how to check if specific child element is applied to remove parent div of ng-content?

Tags: html, angular, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal, angular11

I'm using **Angular 11** and I'm going to detect if my component has any child element with `[footer]` attribute; then if there is no child element with that selector, I will not show **modal-footer**.

**bs-modal.component.html:**

```html
<div class="modal fade" id="{{id}}">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <ng-content select="[header]"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <ng-content select="[body]"></ng-content>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**app.component.html:**

```html
<app-bs-modal [id]="'user-upsert-modal'">
      <div header>
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Modal title</h5>
        <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"> 
        </button>
      </div>
      <div body>
        ...
      </div>
<!-- FOOTER IS HERE OR NOT -->
      <div footer>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
</app-bs-modal>
```

Now when I remove `<div footer>...</div>` from **app.component.ts**, there is still a `<div class="modal-footer">...</div>`, because only the content is not applied.

So, how to check if  is not applied, to remove **modal-footer** element by something like ***ngIf**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
// add modalFooter reference variable here
 <div #modalFooter class="modal-footer" *ngIf="displayFooter">
     <ng-content select="[footer]"></ng-content>
 </div>
```

bs-modal.component.ts:

```
export class BSModalComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild('modalFooter', { static: false }) modalFooter: ElementRef;
  // set displayFooter to true so the *ngIf is true and we can then decide
  // to hide or show it
  displayFooter = true;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // if the modal footer does not have any child nodes, make displayFooter false
    setTimeout(() => {
      if (this.modalFooter.nativeElement.children.length === 0) {
        this.displayFooter = false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I have below results with your solution:
1- when using `{ static: true }`:
 `core.js:6210 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'nativeElement' of undefined
    at BsModalComponent.ngAfterViewInit (bs-modal.component.ts:24)`
2- when using `{ static: false }` :
`ERROR Error: NG0100: ExpressionChangedAfterItHasBeenCheckedError: Expression has changed after it was checked. Previous value: 'true'. Current value: 'false'.. Find more at https://angular.io/errors/NG0100`

Comment: I hate the expression has changed error and I read this every time to hopefully find a fix for it: https://blog.angular-university.io/angular-debugging/. Try keeping `static: false` and wrapping the logic in a `setTimeout`. I have edited the answer and have it shown in the answer.